# Strict coordinator job ordering on Oozie

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

I have a coordinator on oozie that runs a series of tasks, each of which depends on the output of the last. 
Each task outputs a dated folder and looks for the output of its predecessor using

```
${coord:latest(0)}
```

This all worked fine on my dev cluster when nothing else was running; every 5 minutes oozie would queue up another job, and in that 5 minutes the previous job had run so when the new job was set up it would see the directory it needed.

I run into problems on the production cluster; the jobs get submitted, but are put in a queue and don't run for a while, but still every 5 minutes oozie queues up another one, and in its initialization stage it is assigned its 'previous' folder, which hasn't been created yet as its predecessor hasn't run so the 'latest' function gives it the same input as the previous job. I then end up with 10 jobs all taking the same input...

What I need is a way of strictly preventing the next job in a coordinator sequence from even being created until its predecessor has finished running.
Is there a way this can be done?

Thanks for reading

Comment: What is the frequency you have specified for the co-oord ?

Comment: Have a look at these examples, https://github.com/yahoo/oozie/wiki/Oozie-Coord-Use-Cases I am not sure if it is the best idea but myabe you can use `Coordinator Job With Timeouts` example to set a timeout and eliminate the piled up same jobs

Comment: Sorry, I've missed a key bit of info there - the frequency is set to daily, but we have a backlog of older data to import so it's scheduling jobs more frequently than that as their nominal run time is in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the exact use case that Oozie designed to solve. Oozie will wait all data dependency before launch.

Please try to understand the following configs in your coordinator.xml

```
    <datasets>
        <dataset name="my_data" frequency="${coord:days(1)}" initial-instance="2013-01-27T00:00Z">
            <uri-template>YOUR_DATA/${YEAR}${MONTH}${DAY}</uri-template>
        </dataset>
    ...
    <datasets>

    <input-events>
        <data-in name="my_data" dataset="my_data">
            <instance>${coord:current(-1)}</instance>
        </data-in>
    </input-events>

    <output-events>
        <data-out name="my_data" dataset="my_data">
           <instance>${coord:current(0)}</instance>
        </data-out>
    </output-events>
```

the "coord:current(-1)" in input-events means the previous output. It will interpret the dataset URI teamplate to "yesterday", and Oozie will check whether the data exist in HDFS by checking a success flag, which by default is an empty file named "_SUCCESS", right under the output directory. Oozie will keep waiting this flag before launching the current workflow.

btw, you can also set

```
<coordinator-app name="my_coordinator" frequency="${coord:days(1)}" start="${start_time}" end="${end_time}" ...>
```

to define start time and end time of a coordinator job, so you can catch up backlog data.

Comment: We had considered using 'coord:current(-1)' but we cannot guarantee that data will always be available for a given day, in which case we want to fall back to the previous day's output, hence we used 'coord:latest(0)'. In the case where multiple jobs materialise, this is evaluated before the previous job finishes and the wrong input is chosen. It seems impossible to be regulate materialisation though so we will have to reconfigure the rest of our process to be compatible with this method.

Comment: I try to understand the scenario but still a little confused. If a new job depend on previous jobs output, then how can it get parallel? If you don't need to catch up backlog data, have you tried copy the output to another location, and use that location as the only input of your entire workflow? I mean this location only store the latest result.

Comment: Each job depends on the previous job's output, but it can't guarantee that the previous job ran successfully on the previous day, so it takes the 'coord:latest(0)' folder. We could have each job output its data to a single common folder, but we'd still need a way of ensuring that the latest job that was going to run had finished.

Comment: Then I think setting the concurrency of coordinator to 1 would be enough right?